# Inverse function derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

I want to show the following:

> If a function $f$ has $k$ continuous derivatives, then the inverse $g$ also has $k$ continuous derivatives. The derivatives of $f \ne0$.

I was trying to show this by inducting to use the Inverse Function Theorem as a base case. However, I didn't have any luck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: Yeah, it makes logical sense, however, I need to find a way to show it for an arbitrary function with k continuous derivatives.

Comment: The example was to show that the result doesn't hold in that generality. You would need to have more information on the function. $f(x)=x^3$ has derivatives of every order, but $f^{-1}(x)=x^{1/3}$ has infinite derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: I forgot a stipulation. I apologize.

Comment: Does the relation $f^{-1}'(a)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a)}$ help?

Comment: That is the Inverse Function Theorem. I do not know how to use it to show anything about the following derivatives.

Comment: Did you not understand Bettybel's posts?  You **cannot** prove that.  It is not true!  $f(x)= x^3$ is a counter example.

Comment: @user247327 There is an updated condition that $f'$ is non-zero everywhere.

Comment: Apply the Inverse Function Theorem and induction on $k$.

Comment: That is what I attempted @Bettybel . However, I struggled to complete this induction. Could you possibly show me how to manage that?